# where can i get a free 12.10 ubuntu install disc

Tags: system-installation

My friend has an older 2006 Dell laptop media edition with ms win xp and wants to run linux ubuntu 12.10 but, cannot download the desktop version offered here... is there a place to get the install disc for free mailed to him? On his 2005 HP he successfully downloaded 12.04 but lost his laptops wireless connection in the process and he dont want to be tethered by the ac cord so he went back to windows but really wants what linux is open source . thank you for any info on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy live CD's online for a couple of dollars/pounds. That is your best bet if you don’t want to download it. I would strongly suggest just getting some form of internet access and download it and put it on a pen drive or CD.

http://www.thelinuxshop.co.uk/catalog/index.php?cPath=21

This site above sells live CD's for really cheap.

Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill, he is online but has had nothing but problems with the download on ubuntu I will tell him and pass along the info...again,Thank You

Comment: No bother if the question has been answered then mark it so, please.